# writing a simple bootloader in c/c++

Tags: bootloader

i need to write a simple bootloader that run on pc boot and run the command dir(getting the list of files and folders on the usb drive(i am using a bootable usb))
by this instruction:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28067/Boot-Into-Your-Own-Hello-World-Application?msg=4756180#xx4756180xx

this is my asm file which i then by using NASM make a bin file from it an then make an iso from it to put it on my usb.

```
;**************************************************
; Hello World OS Boot loader
; Designed by Arnav
; http://pendorasoft.byethost15.com/
;**************************************************

[BITS 16]
[ORG 0x0000]

; code located at 0000:7C00, adjust segment registers
      cli
      mov     ax, 0x07C0
      mov     ds, ax
      mov     es, ax
      mov     fs, ax
      mov     gs, ax

; create stack
      mov     ax, 0x0000
      mov     ss, ax
      mov     sp, 0xFFFF
      sti

; post message
      mov     si,msgHello
      call    DisplayMessage
      mov     si, msgEnd
    call    DisplayMessage
     hlt  


; Display Message
 DisplayMessage:
      lodsb                                       ; load next character
      or      al, al                              ; test for NUL character
      jz      .DONE
      mov     ah, 0x0E                            ; BIOS teletype
      mov     bh, 0x00                            ; display page 0
      mov     bl, 0x07                            ; text attribute
      int     0x10                                ; invoke BIOS
      jmp     DisplayMessage
  .DONE:
      ret          

; data section
msgHello  db 0x0D, 0x0A, "Hello World", 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x00          
msgEnd  db 0x0D, 0x0A, "That's all folks!!!", 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x00           

;ASM Signature
      TIMES 510-($-$$) DB 0
      DW 0xAA55
```

but i don't want to print something on the screen.instead i want it to show list of files and folders on my usb
how should i complete my code?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm wrong, but at the stage of the bootloader the computer has no clue about DOS, Linux, Windows, etc... so you cannot execute an OS dependant operation. For that you need to have an operating system loaded.

If you need to print the content of drive C you will need to implement the hard work all yourself... ie: read the FAT structures, the names, etc ...

A (pascal) source for this functionality can be found at: https://sites.google.com/site/fritzone/longfilenames and search for an old edition of TechHelp (http://www.danielsays.com/ss-gallery-dos-tech-help-60.html) which has the required documentation too...

Comment: so there is not an easy way to do this?.getting the list of a drive(like a dir command) in a bootloader.

Comment: no,  because  in  the  boot  loader  you  do not know what OS and/or  file system is on the disk.

Comment: what if we boot with a bootable usb(which contains the assembly for bootloader) and then can we get the list of files in that usb?.i updated my assembly(which now only shows a little string).

Comment: What file system is on that USB? Fat? Fat32, NTFS, ext4, CDFS... ? If you know this you can get the list of files by writing appropriate methods to search for and list them.

Comment: i'm going to use fat32 on that.

Comment: Ok. Then maybe one of these will be of help: http://code.ohloh.net/file?fid=wF1C0tFKNLg2RvOfY7quNEBNQsY&cid=v2M6ORahT5A&s=&fp=290333&mp=&projSelected=true#L0 and http://code.google.com/p/jallib/source/browse/trunk/project/fat32_new/fat32.jal

Comment: thank you but i could find any help.is there any way to do what i want to do with bios intrrupts like 0x13?.

Comment: with 0x13  you  can  read a  sector ( or  more)  from a  disk,  however  for interpreting  the  data  you  will  still  need  to  have a  clear  understanding  of  the  content  of  the  data. ie.  the  structures  of a fat32  file  system.  the 0x13  is  one  level  below  what  you  are  trying  to  achieve.  you  want OS  level  access,  while 0x13  provides  hardware  level  access  for  the data